# Same app for multiple clients and custom stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deployment, client

We have the same app source (with some custom "if x client then") and basically the same SQL Server database structure. But, some clients need slightly different stored procedures.

What would be best practice in this scenario for long term maintaining the databases and keeping the correct structure? As of now, for example when I change the procedure in one database and need to do the same in 9/10 others I just ALTER procedure and USE different database. But, I can't keep track of which procedures are different in that special snowflake client.

Any ideas? The plan is of course to get more clients so that's looking for trouble.

I try to push the "one fits all" concept but hey, what can you do...

Maybe have that "if x client then" as case statement in a SQL Server stored procedure and then you can just ALTER mindlessly?

Comment: One thing that I have seen used is (1) create a new stored procedure for the given client, with some client identifier embedded in the name (e.g. `getOrder_ClientX`). You can then either (1) embed a call to the new version and RETURN in the original sproc, or (2) if called from an application, you can have the call check for the _ClientX version before calling the main version. There are at least two other methods I can think of - Schema specific versions, and nested sprocs.

Comment: Nested Sprocs - all stored procedures have a called procedure (e.g. `getOrder`) and a code procedure (`getOrder_Code`). To use custom code, change `getOrder` to reference `getOrder_ClientX` instead.

Comment: One final method - a code repository locally that keeps all custom versions by client, as well as the base code. Getting all code for a given client just requires a pull from your repository, which would pull all custom code + all unmodified base code. A simple report would tell you if a customer had custom code, and a simple DIFF between the base and the custom code would show you the modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Will think about it, because I also like my idea of having it all in the same procedure.